# How to add underline in textformfield when clicked in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In below shown image when we click on textformfield, a wider green border appears on bottom, how do i do it??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        focusNode: userFocus,
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passFocus);
        },
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          hintText: 'Hello world',
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              strokeAlign: 20, color: Colors.green, width: 10.0)),
          ),
       ),
    ),
)
```

[image]